# cascading failures in exec system call

Tags: unix, operating-system, exec, system-calls

I recently learned about the exec() system call in unix. Consider a process executing an exec() and the "transformed process" again executes an exec() and so on. And suddenly the currently executing thing fails, so the context of the previous proc has to be restored.

My question is if the failures keep on occurring in a cascading fashion then would the "original" context still be available. In other words, how much memory can unix spend to go on and saving contexts.

Answer (score 1):

exec() family are *replacing* system calls - they completely replace the original process with the new one, so there is no turning back. To keep the original context use system() call (which is a wrapper around fork() and exec())

Comment: I was told that in case the replaced context fails then the previous context is restored. Isn't that true?

Comment: Not "restored" - it just stays. You continue on with a negative rcode returned by exec.